# Show: $y(t)\to\infty$ implies $x(t)\to\infty$ and $x(t)<y(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> > Suppose $y(t)=\frac{1}{a}\ln(a)+\frac{1}{a}\ln(t+C)$ where $a>0$ is some constant. Then, in particular $y(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$. I want to show that for
> >     $$
> > x'(t)=e^{-ax(t)}-e^{-a y(t)},
> > $$
> >     this implies (1) $x(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ and (2) there exists some $s>0$ such that $x(t)<y(t)$ for all $t>s$.

My argument for (1) goes as follows.

Assume by contradiction that $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=X\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. that $x$ converges.
Then, since by assumption $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-ay(t)}=0$, there exists some $T>0$ such that
$$
x'(t)>0~\forall t>T.
$$
But this contradicts the convergence of $x$. Hence, $x(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

For (2) my idea is again to use contradiction:

Suppose $x(t)\geqslant y(t)$, then $x'(t)\leqslant 0$ since $e^{-a x(t)}\leqslant e^{-a y(t)}$. Dont know if this can give a contradiction.

Or maybe since $x(t)<y(t)$ is equivalent to $x'(t)>0$ it is better to show directly that $x'(t)>0$.

Comment: $x(t)$ could still be oscillating, right?

Comment: @pegasus Why do you think so?

Comment: Why not? You have only "checked" for $x$ converging and for $x\to+\infty$. More things can happen to $x$, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: I see your point, thanks! Is it possible to rule that out? I do not see it.

Comment: But how can $x$ oscillate? We know by assumption that the term $e^{-ay(t)}\to 0$, so for $t$ large enough, this term is arbitrarily small and thus $x'(t)$ is always positive and so $x$ cannot oscillate, because this would require changes between $x'<0$ and $x'>0$. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @user710655 No, if $x'(t)$ is strictly positive $x$ cannot oscillate. But still your conclusion that this contradicts the convergence of $x$ is false.
If $x'$ is strictly positive but becomes smaller and smaller your function $x$ still can converge, e.g. take $x(t) = \arctan(t)$, then $x'(t) > 0$ but $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I see. Too bad. ;( This was my only idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to argument 1), if $x(t)\le M$, then $e^{-ax(t)}\ge e^{-aM}$ and for $t$ large enough the $e^{-ay(t)}$ term will be smaller than half of that, so that you get a positive minimal slope for $x$, contradicting the boundedness.

In general if $x'=f(y)-f(x)$ with an increasing $f$, then $y(t)$ is a transient curve and at any point in time $x$ will move towards it. This means that $x$ lags behind, and for an increasing $y$ this means that eventually the $x$-curve comes to move below the $y$-curve.

---

But now with the given form of $y$ you can even compute more. Set $u(t)=e^{ax(t)}$ and insert $y$ to get the linear DE
$$
u'(t)=ae^{ax(t)}x'(t)=a-\frac{u(t)}{t+C}
\\
(t+C)u(t)=\frac{a}2(t+C)^2+D\implies u(t)=\frac{a}2(t+C)+\frac{D}{t+C}
$$
which clearly is unbounded and eventually smaller than $e^{ay(t)}=a(t+C)$.

Comment: At some point $t_1$, you get $y(t_1)=x(t_0)$. If $x$ were falling for all this time, then there is a crossover point $t_*$ so that $x(t_*)=y(t_*)$ in-between and $x'>0$ after that. So your scenario is not correct from the ODE alone.

Comment: Yes, it might be wrong if $y$ does not grow monotonically towards infinity. If it has oscillations that are significant enough, then the tracking by $x$ of $y$ might cause $x$ to temporally be larger than $y$.

Comment: You can cross the null-cline $x=y(t)$ only in the direction of the vector field, from left to right. Or increase a little, then you can cross the curve $x=y(t)+\varepsilon$ only going downwards, as the slope there is $-e^{-ay(t)}(1-e^{-a\varepsilon})$. Thus crossing the line $x=y(t)$  upwards is not possible. (If $y$ itself oscillates, then it is possible that the downwards slope of of $y$ is less steep than the vector field, so a crossing is not excluded.)

Comment: I said from left to right, or horizontally. For a growing nullcline this means from atop the graph to below it. You have to compare the slightly positive slope at $x=y−ε$ to the positive slope of $y$ at that same time. To cross from below to atop you need that the slope of $x$ is larger than the one of $y$.

Comment: Am I right that, if $x(T)=y(T)$, i.e., $x'(T)=0$, for some $T>0$, then $x'(t)=0$ **for all** $t>T$?

Answer (score 1):

About your argument for (1):

Firstly, I don't think that the implication that there is some $T$ such that $x'(t)>0$ for $t>T$ is true. It could still be that $x(t)-y(t)$ alternates signs.

Moreover, even if you manage to show that $x'(t)>0$ eventually, a function being strictly increasing does not guarantee that it does not converge. Think about $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I see your points, thank you! Now that my attempts failed so badly, I am of course interested how the statement can be proven (or maybe the statement is even wrong).

Comment: I am very sorry, I completely overlooked that $y$ is given even explicitly, I added this to my post. Sorry!

Comment: @user710655, I think you should post a new question with that as my answer and our discussion now seem off.